# How to increase JRuby Trinidad pool size?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, trinidad-gem

When I first boot up Trinidad via "jruby -S trinidad"
I get the msg:

```
added application to pool, size now = 1
```

How do I increase the size of this pool in my config/trinidad.yml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/trinidad/trinidad/blob/master/lib/trinidad/configuration.rb

I think `jruby.min.runtimes`(and `jruby.max.runtimes`) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

when using **trinidad.yml** it looks something like this :

```
---
  address: localhost # set '*' to bind to all interfaces
  port: 3000 # port where Trinidad is going to be runnin
  #environment: production # specify with `trinidad -e production`
  jruby_min_runtimes: 10 # min number of JRuby runtimes to use
  jruby_max_runtimes: 10 # max number of JRuby runtimes to use
  #threadsafe: true # implies min runtimes == max runtimes == 1
```